# How to get the correct native memory address in electron + node-ffi-napi

Tags: node.js, electron, memory-address, ffi, node-ffi

I can get the correct native memory address if I use `Node.js` directly such as:

```
// eg. native dll writen in rust; Of course, this part can be implemented in C or C++ or any others.
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn example_concat(
  a: *const c_char,
  b: *const c_char
) -> *mut c_char
{
  let sa = CStr::from_ptr(a).to_str().expect("cannot to_str from a");
  let sb = CStr::from_ptr(b).to_str().expect("cannot to_str from b");
  let sr = format!("{}{}", sa, sb);
  let cr = CString::new(sr).expect("cannot create cr from sr");
  println!("[from native lib] cr={} *=0x{:X}", cr.to_str().expect("cannot to_str from cr"), cr.as_ptr() as c_ulonglong);
  cr.into_raw()
}
```

```js
// tester.js
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');
const ref = require('ref-napi');
const str = ref.types.CString;
const lib = ffi.Library( 'lib.dll', { 'example_concat': [ "char *", [ str, str ] ] } );
const buffer = lib.example_concat( "su", "shi" );
console.log( '[from tester.js]', buffer.hexAddress(), buffer.readCString() );
```

The result of `node tester.js` is:

```sh
[from native lib] cr=sushi *=0x1E7B3B3E8C0
[from tester.js] 000001E7B3B3E8C0 sushi
```

It's expected, no problems. But, the problem happen to me if I use the similar FFI method with `react-electron` system.

```js
// App.js in react-electron Node.js project
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const ffi = remote.require( 'ffi-napi' );
const ref = remote.require( 'ref-napi' );
const str = ref.types.CString;
const lib = ffi.Library( 'lib.dll', { 'example_concat': [ "char *", [ str, str ] ] } );
const buffer = lib.example_concat( "su", "shi" );
console.log( '[from App.js(electron)]', ref.hexAddress( buffer ), ref.readCString( buffer ) ); // <-- It returns wrong memory address!!
```

The result of this electron version is:

```sh
[from native lib] cr=sushi *=0x2BFA2F07A10
[from App.js(electron)] 000002BFA3BA7230 sushi
```

How can I get the correct native memory address in a project using `electron`?

---

- os = Microsoft Windows 10 (64-Bit) 10.0.19041.153
- node = 13.5.0
- node-ffi-napi = 2.4.7
- node-ffi-ref = 1.4.3
- react = 16.13.0
- electron = 8.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this case. In posted situation, I used `nodeIntegration: true` then I implemented the example used `const remote = window.require('electron').remote` and `remote.require` features. Then, `AddressForArgs`(†1) via `ref.HexAddress` returns electron client based address maybe ( I don't know more internals of the node-ref-napi, node-ffi-napi and electron just now ).

Therefore, I tried change to `nodeIntegration: false` setting with `preload` features.

```js
// preload.js
window.ffi = require( 'ffi-napi' );
window.ref = require( 'ref-napi' );
```

```js
// App.js ( Fixed to the preload feature based )
// const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const ffi = window.ffi; //remote.require( 'ffi-napi' );
const ref = window.ref; //remote.require( 'ref-napi' );
```

Then, it works expected! Well done, congraturations to me!!

(†1): https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-napi/blob/ed19a20370394b0b1914566f4ea9b5354b475732/src/binding.cc#L72